# take no of neighbours from the given index of list. what is the best practice or effiecient performance for given solution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, performance

I want to take (c=3) number of elements from the given index (idx) of (a_list) list.
**Input**:

```
a_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]  
idx = 4  
c = 3        # no of neighbours to take
```

**Output**:
`[2,3,4,6,7,8]`

**Solution 1:** Append forward and backward elemnts through separate loops.

```
def get_result(a_list, idx, c):

  for i in range(1,c+1):
    result.append(a_list[idx - i])

  for i in range(1,c+1):
    result.append(a_list[idx + i])

  return result
```

**Solution 2:** Make two separate list for forward and backward elements with one for loop and merge.

```
def get_result(a_list, idx, c):
  forward_list, backward_list = [],[]

  for i in range(1,c+1):
    forward_list.append(a_list[idx - i])
    backward_list.append(a_list[idx + i])

  result = [forward_list, backward_list]
  return result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to use slices and not use loops to construct the result manually:

```
def get_result(a_list, idx, c):
    return a_list[idx-c:idx] + a_list[idx+1:idx+c+1]

>>> get_result([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 4, 3)
[2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]
```

After all, your use case is exactly what slices are for: extract a contiguous [or at least regular] subsequence of a sequence.

Since `idx-c` might turn out to be negative, you might add some logic to cover that case, e.g. you could use

```
a_list[max(0, idx-c):idx]
```

for the first summand.

Comment: This will create two new lists first and then merge it similar to given solution 2. It will take more memory than the first solution I guess.  if memory is my priority should I go with the first solution?